# Is it possible to schedule closing a named app

Tags: task-management

Is there an app (or other way) to schedule the closing of only one named application at a particular time each day? My situation is I use the Night Mode app at night to reduce the screen brightness but if I forget to turn it off when I go out the next day the screen is so dark to be unusable in daylight. So I'd like to schedule to kill Night Mode at 9 am every day (but not other apps).

(I've found ones that turn off the speakers after a configurable time for listening to music as you go to sleep, or general task killers with auto killing of background apps, but nothing to kill just one app at a set time.)

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to Android Enthusiasts !
We are sorry, but this question is clearly in violation of the regulations of this site. Please read http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic before asking a question here, and do help us prevent spam or other such questions that might be a burden to the moderators. However, for your question, see https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=il.co.kix.minitasker. Thank you!

Comment: @rjt.rockx Though the title looks like an explicit app request, OP signaled to be open for any solution ("an app (or other way) to" achieve X). So it looks like a valid "how can I achieve X on Android" question. So you might go on makeing your recommendation an answer (I just had the same in mind with the "big" *Tasker*, but that would be like stealing the hint from your comment for my rep :)

Comment: @rjt.rockx. Thanks for the suggestion of Condi minitasker, that does indeed have a feature to kill an app at a set time, though it didn't actually work in my case so I'll try to fix that or try other similar apps in the 'multi-purpose scheduling assistant' vein. As for being an inappropriate question, I understood that clause being to avoid non-useful subjective 'this app is better than that one' threads, but I just wanted a factual "how can I do this?" knowing the answer was probably an app.

Comment: @Izzy , Tasker might be a bit too complex, and it has a steep learning curve for users who don't know much about the details of an Android system. 
Well, if it is okay, then I have no objection. I just wanted to help, that's all. 
By the way, you could have gone ahead with the 'Tasker' recommendation. There are way too many to be mentioning each and every one here, so, the best could be mentioned. I just gave it as a hint, not as the correct answer, feeling that it might be useful. You could have asked me to delete it and post it as an answer, I thought.

Comment: @Uberdude could you try if *Tasker* does that for you? There's a 7-day trial available for that (see the [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info)). This one should be relative simple: Condition is *Time* (with the time you want), and task is *App › Kill App* (select the app to kill).

Comment: I tried but failed to install the Tasker trial, but I tried using llama but that didn't work either. I think the problem is as of Android 2.something one app isn't allowed to kill another unless it gets root permission. I'm running non rooted Samsung S3 flavour android 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Get a free app called [automateit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage&hl=en) then once you know how to use it, you can create a rule by using the time trigger and set it to 9 am, use the kill app action to kill whatever then you name the rule and set it to be active every time, save it then your done!

Comment: I don't see any action that would kill an app.

Comment: Asking to gain points to download rules.